# STM32F4 ADC+DMA wrong values

Tags: stm32, adc, dma, hal

I try to setup STM32F407ZGT6 chip to work with ADC throught DMA, currently I'm using HAL lib for fast prototype but have some problem. I set up ADC as 3 chanel **Scan** **Continous** mode using DMA in circular mode with Peripheral-to-Memory mode with length **Word**.
I checked max freq for ADC (36MHz) and divide my CoreFreq (72MHz) by 4.
[image: ADC HAL Setup]

[image: ADC DMA Setup]

In code I create variable `uint32_t adc_value[3]`
And run ADC `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *)&adc_value, 3);` before main loop.
For voltage adjustments and tests I use 1kOhm potentiometer, but while I change resistance nothing happeng, and values jump randomly between 2047, 4096 (2 values, I mean I can see only 2 values).

Whats interesting I used the same setup in STM32F103 (BluePill) and all works fine. Maybe I missed something, because F4 chip has more wider settings. Thanks

Comment: Check system frequencies. F407 is capable of running at 168MHz system clock, APB2 prescaler should be 2 in this case. If it is a custom board, check power on all inputs, connection of the decoupling capacitors. Perhaps try higher values of ADC prescaler.

Comment: Thanks to @Flexz! I checked all params and hardware part and decade to resolder chip and all strange parts. And aftrer that all works as expected! So problem was on bad PCB asembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prablem was on hardware, after resolder chip and some problem parts all works fine.
In my case i use that board from Ali [image]